# If the variance of two variables are equal, then the covariance is the variance?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, descriptive-statistics

If I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ and their variance is the same, i.e.,  $Var(X)=Var(Y)$.
Does this mean $Var(X)=Var(Y)=Cov(X,Y)$ ?

Comment: Roll two fair dice one on Tuesday and the other on Saturday. Their distributions have the same spread (and the same variance), but their *covariance* should presumably be zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## In short, no.

---

Consider the counterexample that if two normal variables both have unit variance, their covariance could be zero.

---

Alternatively, for geometric motivation, consider that two vectors can have the same length while pointing in perpendicular/orthogonal directions.